# FluentValidator isEmpty Not validate for first item

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I have a fluent validator:

```
RuleFor(x => x.TypeTest)
          .NotEmpty()
          .WithMessage(x => string.Format(MessagesValidation.ValeurRequise, nameof(x.TypeTest)))
```

TypeTest is enum type

```
public enum TypeTest
  {
    A,
    B,
    C,
  }
```

- Even I give `TypeTest = "A"`  validator doesn't valid it and return an error.
- Solution but I didnt Like it:

```
public enum TypeTest
  {
    Empty = 0,
    A,
    B,
    C,
  }
```

is there any other solution ? please.

**Updated**

the problem is anytime I give the first value, it consider as Empty, and validator return an error. that is why I add a new value as Empty but im asking if there's an other way ?

Comment: What do you want to validate here? If TypeTest is nullable then use .NotNull() instead. If TypeTest is not nullable then .NotEmpty() does not make sense here, TypeTest always has value A, B or C.

Comment: the problem is anytime I give the first value, it consider as Empty, and validaotr return an error

Comment: What value of property TestType would you like to return an error then? If TestType property is not nullable then property will always have value A, B or C. Even if property is not set explicitly, its value is `default(TestType)` = `TestType.A`, that's why introduction of Empty solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to validate an enum type using NotEmpty() method? Enum can never be empty. It always has a default value.
If you want to validate value of an enum type, you should use IsInEnum() method.
Also, you can't assign a string to an enum type as you've written in your question.

Comment: Yes you are but even with IsInEnum it return error for the first value

Comment: I want to check if the attribute is given too not only if inEnum or not, it's a required value

Answer (score 0):

If you want `TypeTest` to allow for "empty" values, make the property nullable:

```
public TypeTest? TypeTest { get; set; }
//             ^ (the question mark after the type allows nulls to be assigned)
```

That should get the "NotEmpty()" validator working, but the downside is introducing an additional possible value for an enum: `null`. Depending on your use case, a `null` value might be desirable. Changing the type of the property from `TypeTest` to `TypeTest?` will require downstream code changes. Anything relying on the `TypeTest` property will need to access the enum value using `x.TypeTest.Value` rather than just `x.TypeTest`.